# Having a different color for active point in line graph

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I suspect this is straight forward, but I cannot deduce whether it can be done via dygraph options or via css.

I have created a standard line graph.  When I mouse over the graph the active point shows up as a 5px circle.  All I now want to do is to be able to style the circle so that instead of being the same color as the series line it is a different color.

I have read the documentation but cannot figure this out.  I was looking at the Dygraph.Circles.CIRCLE example, but struggle to get how I have a different color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this example

[Custom-Circles](http://dygraphs.com/tests/custom-circles.html)

in the last example the highlighted point for the emoji changes on hover

Comment: I thought I could have done this in a simpler fashion, but I have adapted it to what I need and it works as expected.  Thanks